# Using a shift() to compare rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I would like to find the nearest 'Quote' for each 'Trade' in the column `Type`, and use `shift()` to pull in data from  `Bid price` of the nearest "Quote" to `Prevailing price` of "Trade".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Quote', '1.4', '1.4'],
                        ['Quote', '1.6', '1.6'],
                        ['Trade', '10.0', 'NaN'],
                        ['Quote', '1.7', '1.7'],
                        ['Trade', '11.0', 'NaN'],
                        ['Trade', '11.0', 'NaN'],
                       ['Trade', '11.0', 'NaN']],
                  columns=['Type', 'Bid price', 'Prevailing price'])
df['Prevailing price'] = df['Bid price'].shift().where(df['Type'] == 'Trade',df['Bid price'])
print df
```

I am getting the error in the output: for continuous 'Trade' , the result is based on the `Bid price`  of the previous' Trade ' instead of `Bid price` of the nearest "Quote", like `index 4-6`.

```
Type    Bid price   Prevailing price
0   Quote   1.4     1.4
1   Quote   1.6     1.6
2   Trade   10.0    1.6
3   Quote   1.7     1.7
4   Trade   11.0    1.7
5   Trade   11.0    11.0
6   Trade   11.0    11.0
```

Desired Output:

```
Type    Bid price   Prevailing price
0   Quote   1.4     1.4
1   Quote   1.6     1.6
2   Trade   10.0    1.6
3   Quote   1.7     1.7
4   Trade   11.0    1.7
5   Trade   11.0    1.7
6   Trade   11.0    1.7
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If possible replace `Trade` rows in `Bid price` by missing values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then forward filling last non missing values by `ffill` use:

```
df['Prevailing price'] = df['Bid price'].mask(df['Type'] == 'Trade').ffill()
print (df)
    Type Bid price Prevailing price
0  Quote       1.4              1.4
1  Quote       1.6              1.6
2  Trade      10.0              1.6
3  Quote       1.7              1.7
4  Trade      11.0              1.7
5  Trade      11.0              1.7
6  Trade      11.0              1.7
```